# KeyNotFoundException when iterating through Dictionary

Tags: c#, exception, dictionary, key

I have a seemingly simple piece of code that is consistently throwing an error that I wouldn't expect to be possible:

```
// Private member
private Dictionary<InputField, bool> m_Completed;

// Later on, during some method
foreach (InputField filter in this.m_Completed.Keys)
    if (this.m_Completed[filter])
        completedCount += 1;
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary
```

This is coming from the "if" statement in the loop.

To me, this implies that the iterator has become desynchronised from the actual keys of the dict. Is this possible? There is no threading going on.

Is my workflow just wrong? I can think of a few other ways to get my count, but I'd still like to know why my code is throwing an error.

Comment: What is `InputField`?

Comment: I can think of two things: a) the dictionary is being accessed concurrently and another thread is removing entries (but I don't think that's the issue here), or b) `InputField.GetHashCode` is returning inconsistent values.

Comment: As a test, does the problem go away if you replace InputField with another type e.g. int ?

Comment: Is is possible that instances of InputField are changing along the way? Are they dependant on something external, like date or time or something..?

Comment: They're all good ideas.

I had hoped to avoid gumming up StackOverflow with more Unity3D issues. InputField inherits (somewhere down the line) from Unity3Ds MonoBehaviour class.

The strange thing is, the error only occurs in the final build. I'm starting to think Unity does something strange with it's classes in builds.

Comment: Works fine with <int, bool> (of course!) Backing up the idea @dcastro had, is there a custom implementation of GetHashCode in Inputfield or in any of Inputfield bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `InputField` or one of its base classes implements `GetHashCode` in a way such that it won't return the same value for the lifetime of the instance.

This completely breaks the functionality of a `Dictionary` or an `HashSet`, which rely on a consistent hash code.

As such, a possible solution would be to make your `InputField` override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. If it already overrides these, you'll need to fix the implementation.

You'll find *great* guidelines for proving a proper implementation on Eric Lippert's blog post [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://ericlippert.com/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode/).

In this case, this is the guideline that seems to be missing from the current implementation:

> Guideline: the integer returned by GetHashCode should never change
>
> Ideally, the hash code of a mutable object should be computed from only fields which cannot mutate, and therefore the hash value of an object is the same for its entire lifetime.

Comment: Thanks dcastro. I've taken this problem to the Unity forums, given they're responsible for the base class here. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/236112-MonoBehaviour-as-Dictionary-key-KeyNotFoundException